# How can I query multiple databases by name that reside on a Azure SQL server using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-server

I want to be able to run some ad-hoc queries to get some fast results.  The following will return the number of rows in table `foobar` from two databases that have identical structures.

```
USE Master
GO
select count(*) from MyFirstDB.dbo.foobar;
select count(*) from MySecondDB.dbo.foobar;
```

This works fine for SQL Server, but SQL Azure returns errors.  I read that you with SQL Azure you cannot change the database context in the query window of SSMS.  Is there a way to make this work?  What happens if I want to create a join across two databases?

Comment: For the cross db queries: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: To run the same query against multiple databases in SSMS, you could create a registered server group in SSMS containing the desired Azure databases. Then right-click on the group name and select new query to open a query window. Queries run in the multi-server query window with 1 or 2-part names will execute against each database and SSMS will combine the results (e.g. `select count(*) from dbo.foobar;`) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Ones needs to create external data source and table that is linked to another server. You can use the following code to create one.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credname
WITH IDENTITY = 'username',
SECRET = 'password';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE data_source_name
WITH
(
 TYPE=RDBMS,
 LOCATION='server.database.windows.net',
 DATABASE_NAME='databasename',
 CREDENTIAL= credname
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[external_table_name](
 -- Copy column definition
 [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)
WITH
(
DATA_SOURCE = data_source_name,
SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',
OBJECT_NAME = 'tablename'
)

select *
from dbo.[external_table_name]

DROP EXTERNAL TABLE [external_table_name]

DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [data_source_name]

DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credname
```